# My datagridview don't resize when the form was in full-screen and i resize

Tags: c#, datagridview, resize, minimize

I tried anchor the datagridview to top, left, right and it works fine when its not maximixed, but when i maximize the form and then minimize it again datagridview don't resize.

Comment: It works on my VS2017 Framework 4.6.1. Have you tried to erase it and add another?

Comment: Doubtful. Have you 'described'  your layout fully to us??

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: You talk about Window Form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dock property as below:

- Fill: If you want your datagridview always display in full screen mode.
- TOP: If you want your datagridview always show at the top.
- Left: If you want your datagridview always show at the left.
- Right: If you want your datagridview always show at the right.
- Bottom: If you want your datagridview always show at the bottom.

I hope this will help you.